# How to use Ucanaccess lib in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, ms-access, ucanaccess

Im trying to use ms access database in android studio but no success i searched a lot & tried everything i could find about ucanaccess but didnt work please help.
First i added the 5 jar files in project structure which automatically added in gradle file

```
        dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('libs\\commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\hsqldb.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jackcess-2.1.11.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\ucanaccess-4.0.4.jar')
}
```

**In MainActivity I added this code**

```
package access.db.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ImportUtil;
import net.ucanaccess.converters.TypesMap.AccessType;
import net.ucanaccess.ext.FunctionType;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try{

            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");//Loading Driver
            Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\SGF.accdb");//Establishing Connection
            System.out.println("Connected Successfully");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in connection");


        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the logcat output**

```
11-25 00:41:28.414 15549-15549/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10061: Read-only file system
11-25 00:41:28.414 15549-15549/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
11-25 00:41:28.414 15549-15549/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-25 00:41:28.536 15549-15549/access.db.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-25 00:41:28.581 15549-15549/access.db.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
11-25 00:41:28.581 15549-15549/access.db.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
11-25 00:41:28.639 15549-15549/access.db.myapplication I/System.out: Error in connection
11-25 00:41:28.652 15549-15570/access.db.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-25 00:41:28.657 15549-15549/access.db.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map...
11-25 00:41:28.693 15549-15570/access.db.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 00:41:28.697 15549-15570/access.db.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaf034d00: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-25 00:41:28.698 15549-15570/access.db.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf034d00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf039420)
11-25 00:41:28.707 15549-15570/access.db.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-25 00:41:28.714 15549-15570/access.db.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf034d00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf039420)
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: how to add bounty on this question

Comment: With more than 75 rep, you should see "Start a Bounty" below "Add a Comment".

Comment: @BahaaHany You need to wait two days before a question is eligible for a bounty